# Edit span input

Tags: jquery, rename, html

Okay, my original question wasn't clear at all so I'll try to explain it in a better way.

I'm making a userscript to run on a certain page (wich already exists and the html can't be altered by me directly, only by using JS/Jquery). I'm getting information from that page, and putting it in a variable (wich I already have working).

That information is different for each page, but every page has the same HTML/JS code, only the numbers change. So I want to change the title of each page (the span values, wich are used to describe what the information is) automatically without having to press any buttons, just by loading the page. So all of this ( http://grab.by/tLB6) just by loading the page.

Josh Harrison already posted a reply containing a function, I do beleive that's how it should be done (with a function) so it just runs that function every time a page loads, replacing the span value with my variabele and saving it (saving = pressing ok).

I'm sorry for the long explanation...

```
       var inputName = $("#editInput").val();
       var NewName = "My new text";
       $("#labelText").text(NewName);
```

This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6X8fu/6/ does the same thing I want (but on a different page), but it's written in plain JS. I put a comment before the part that I mean. In this script, it prompts something, then renames it to what was prompted. In my case, I'm getting the info from the page, put it in a variable, then want to rename to that variabeles content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's JS though.

```
 var NewName = "Some text"
 var editspan = document.getElementById('edit');
 var editinput = editspan.getElementsByTagName('input');
 editinput[0].value = (NewName);
 editinput[1].click();
```

Thank you for all your replies :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's the `span` you want to update, do this:

```
var NewName = "My new text";
$("#labelText").text(NewName);
```

If it's the `input`, do this:

```
var NewName = "My new text";
$("#editInput").val(NewName);
```

$element.val() is for getting the value of form elements. $element.val("value") is for setting the value of form elements. $element.text() works the same way for getting and setting, but is for non-user-editable DOM elements.

See http://api.jquery.com/text/ and http://api.jquery.com/val/

**EDIT 2:**

So you want to update the `span` with the value of the `input` on page load. As an added bonus this will continue updating it as you type.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6X8fu/8/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $label = $("#labelText"),
        $input = $("#editInput");

    function updateText() {
        $label.text($input.val());
    }

    // just call the function without binding it to any events. 
    // This block executes inside $(document).ready() so will run as soon as the elements are ready.
    updateText();
    $input.on("keyup", updateText); // also bind to keyup event.

});
```

Comment: Have you tested it? It does not work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6X8fu/1/

Comment: See question: *I want to change the value of a **span***

Comment: Ok, the question and fiddle were unclear. Updated to cover both interpretations!

Comment: Unfortenatly, this does not work. I took some screenshots to explain:

http://grab.by/tLB6

When clicked on, I'm able to alter the spans value, however, I want to do this automatically using Jquery

Edit: I'm sorry if it's a bit unclear, I'm quite new to this and jus trying to learn. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: At the moment, it only changes the value when i click the rename (Herbenoemen) button myself.

Comment: @user3227070 Sounds like you want it to update as you type. See my updated answer.

Comment: I was probably being really unclear. I updated my original question with a decent explanation, wich I should have done in the first place.

Comment: Ok, updated again. I hope this solves your question.